# Web application authentication using React and Flask

Tags: reactjs, azure, authentication, flask, authorization

I am building a web application which uses React on the frontend and Flask on the backend (and deployed to Azure).
I would like to implement user authentication/authorization.

I understand how to implement this with pure Flask, but I am not sure how to achieve this when React is the frontend and Flask on the backend. 
For example:

- Is still Flask handling this or is this done by React?
- If Flask authenticates the users, how do you send passwords in a secure way?
- etc etc etc

Any advice/ link to resources is more than welcome.
I am also open to suggestion on other ways to handle this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's different ways to handle authentication and what you pick depends on the level of security you need and how much time you're willing to invest. 
Sending login data from the client to the server is fairly well protected when you use ssl.

So you build a form in react and send the data with a post over ssl to you backend. After that you can use a token or a session or cookie etc.

There's a nice write up on Flask Authentication in this [blog](https://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/restful-authentication-with-flask)